# I have to print a series using for loop

Tags: java, loops

Here is the series :

```
12345

22345

33345

44445
```

I tried to solve this but it is not coming correct...

Here is the code :

```
    class q14
  {
      public static void main ( )
         {
             int i,j,k;
             for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
                {
                    for (j=i;j<=5;j++)
                      {
                          for (k=1;k<=i;k++)
                             {
                                 System.out.print (i + " ");
                                }
                          System.out.print (j + " ");
                        }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: In what way does this code solves the problem?

Comment: I want the correct way to print this series

Comment: there is no such thing as a *correct way*. There are an infinite amount of programs that can produce this sequence. Furthermore the given series is ambigous as well.

Comment: Dude the ouput of my code is wrong I want to know how to print the series using for loops

Comment: and in order to generate a series, dude, you must first tell the **rule** behind a serie...

Comment: Rule ? I have given the series of numbers to be printed clearly in the question and the rule is you have to print this using for loop. I cannot determine the logic  so thus I just want to know any way of correctly solving this program

Comment: Well `System.out.println("12345\n22345\n33345\n44445");` is a correct way, which shows it is not a serie at all...

Comment: Why is everyone voting down my question ?

Comment: Well some user voted to close the question for the following reason: "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following block should generate the series as you described it.

```
int numberOfLines = 4;
int numberOfDigitsPerLine = 5;

for (int i=1; i<numberOfLines+1; i++){
    for(int j=1; j<=numberOfDigitsPerLine; j++) {
        if(j>=i) {
            System.out.print(j);
        } else {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Change `numberOfLines` and `numberOfDigitsPerLine` as necessary.

**Elaboration:**

First you must analyze the series, by the looks of it the first number starts with 1 and goes onward for 5 digits, the second line goes along 5 digits as well up to 5 as previously but it replaces the first digit with 2.

Moving down the numbers we can see a pattern of which the N-th number will have N amount of N digits followed by consecutive digits up to the number 5.

So in my code above I chose max N to be 4 as you described it, and the numbers go up to 5, these are represented by the variables `numberOfLines` and `numberOfDigitsPerLine` respectively.

The block itself checks what is N at that point (in my block it is represented by `i`) and then proceeds to go towards the max number 5, this is done within the `j` for loop. If j is larger or equal to N then we print j, otherwise we haven't finished printing all of the N's yet so we print N instead.

Comment: Ok I get it now... Nice Logic ! and Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 1; k <= i;k++) 
                System.out.print(i);
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= 5; j++)
                System.out.print(j);
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a third loop for your series

```
for (int j=1;j<=5;j++) {

       for (int k=1;k<=5;k++){   
                    if(k<=j)
                       System.out.print (j + " ");
                       else
                       System.out.print (k + " ");
                 }

       System.out.println();
  }
```

output

```
1 2 3 4 5 
2 2 3 4 5 
3 3 3 4 5 
4 4 4 4 5 
5 5 5 5 5
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/gOq5mf)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j<=5;j++)
        {
            if(i>j)
            {
                for(int x= 1 ; x<=i;x++)
               {
                   System.out.print(i);
                   j++;
               }   
            }                
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```